# Iterating through Vector 8 bytes at a time & performing bitwise operations

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, transform, stdvector

I have a vector of unsigned chars called vector1, I want to iterate through the vector in blocks of 8 bytes and perform a bitwise operation on each block using the std::transform function. The transform function stores the XOR'd data in vector2. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
 for (std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator itr = vector1.begin(); itr != vector1.end(); itr += 8)
 { 
    // vector1 data XOR'd with KEY_IV data and output to vector2
    std::transform(itr, itr += 8, std::begin(KEY_IV), std::begin(vector2), std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());

    if (itr == vector1.end())
      break;
  }
```

This is not performing the way I want it to. I also think there could be a problem due to the fact that I am iterating 8 bytes at a time through the vector and also doing the same inside the transform function. Do I need both (itr, itr += 8) in transform?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Checks vector1 for multiples of 8 and if not, pads out with 0's

```
// check vector1 for multiples of 8, if not, pad out with 0's
for (std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator itr = vector1.begin(); itr != vector1.end(); itr += 8)
{
  if ((vector1.size() % 8) != 0)
  {
    vector1.push_back(fmod(vector1.size(), 8));
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit: nvm, I understood your quenstion the wrong way ^^

Comment: `This is not performing the way I want it to.` What do you mean??

Comment: @gsamaras I have an expected output for the XOR on the data using a cryptographic calculator. When I am looking at vector2 after I have run the transform the values are: 128 '\200', Hex: 0x80. If Vector1 was 5555555555555555 and KEY_IV was 1111111111111111 I would expect vector2 to be 4444444444444444

Comment: `itr += 8` is wrong in transform (order of evaluation of parameter is unspecified): You might want `itr + 8` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42, I added this to my code and you were correct, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating `itr` in the call to `std::transform`. You have unspecified behaviour, because it appears in the argument list again.

```
assert((vector1.size() % 8) == 0, "bad times!");
for (std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator itr = vector1.begin(); itr != vector1.end(); itr += 8)
{ 
  // vector1 data XOR'd with KEY_IV data and output to vector2
  std::transform(itr, itr + 8, std::begin(KEY_IV), std::begin(vector2), std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());
}
```

The `std::begin(vector2)` is suspect too, you are only ever writing to the first 8 elements of `vector2`. Do you mean to advance the destination?

```
assert((vector1.size() % 8) == 0, "bad times!");
auto dest = std::begin(vector2);
for (auto itr = vector1.begin(); itr != vector1.end(); itr += 8)
{ 
  // vector1 data XOR'd with KEY_IV data and output to vector2
  dest = std::transform(itr, itr + 8, std::begin(KEY_IV), dest, std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());
}
```

This can be made safer (discarding the assert), by looping `vector1.size() / 8` times, and then performing a final shorter xor.

```
size_t count = vector1.size() / 8;
auto itr = vector1.begin();
auto dest = std::begin(vector2);
for (; --count; itr += 8)
{ 
  // vector1 data XOR'd with KEY_IV data and output to vector2
  dest = std::transform(itr, itr + 8, std::begin(KEY_IV), dest, std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());
}
std::transform(itr, vector1.end(), std::begin(KEY_IV), dest, std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If I am correct here then assert is a macro that checks the vector is a multiple of 8 yes? If you could look at my edited question at the bottom I have added in code to check if my vector is a multiple of 8, and if not, pad out with 0's

Comment: As for advancing the destination, here is where I may be doing this wrong. I basically want to input plaintext data which is stored in vector1. Perform an XOR on this plaintext data and store this in vector2. This data is then encrypted and appended to a larger vector which I have simply called encryptedData. So the 8 byte blocks of XOR'd data are added to the encryptedData vector which holds everything. I am XORing 8 bytes at a time as I think this will run better, but then again I may be wrong. I am new to this and learning as I go, thanks :)

Comment: Does vector2 initially contain any values? Is it the same size as vector1, or 8?

Comment: Also, if you are intending to *use* this encryption for anything, rather than just writing it as a learning exercise, I strongly advise *not writing it* but instead find a (suitably licensed) library to encrypt for you.

Comment: No vector2 is empty and the XOR'd values are added to it. It might be worth initializing it as 8 bytes also. The encryption is all done for me, I just pass my data to the encrypt functions.

Comment: @Zeus7 If `vector2` starts empty then you need `std::back_inserter(vector2)` which adds a new element to the end each time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will see if I can get it working using these.

Comment: So I have added these to my code but I am still getting vector2 values as 128/0x80. I noticed these values are the same as values as a vector which has no data

Comment: Caleth your code is now working with a slight modification using @Galik std::back_inserter() replacing the dest = std::begin. Thank you both, it is much appreciated.